# Why is Elasticsearch filter showing all records?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.5 and trying to run a filter query on some metrics data. For example:

```
 {
    "_index": "zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2-2017.10.29",
    "_type": "jmx",
    "_id": "AV9lcbNtvbkfeNFaDYH2",
    "_score": 0.00015684571,
    "_source": {
      "metric_value_number": 95721248,
      "path": "/home/ubuntu/etc_logstash/jmx/zabbix_test",
      "@timestamp": "2017-10-29T00:04:31.014Z",
      "@version": "1",
      "host": "18.221.245.150",
      "index": "zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2",
      "metric_path": "zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2.Memory.NonHeapMemoryUsage.used",
      "type": "jmx"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2-2017.10.29",
    "_type": "jmx",
    "_id": "AV9lcbNtvbkfeNFaDYIU",
    "_score": 0.00015684571,
    "_source": {
      "metric_value_number": 0,
      "path": "/home/ubuntu/etc_logstash/jmx/zabbix_test",
      "@timestamp": "2017-10-29T00:04:31.030Z",
      "@version": "1",
      "host": "18.221.245.150",
      "index": "zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2",
      "metric_path": "zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2.ClientRequest.ReadLatency.Count",
      "type": "jmx"
    }
  }
```

I am running the following query:

```
GET /zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2-2017.10.29/jmx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "metric_path" : "zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2.ClientRequest.ReadLatency.Count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Even then if it displaying all records. However, if I use the following text, it works by showing exact matches:

```
  GET /zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2-2017.10.29/jmx/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "metric_path" : "zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2.Memory.NonHeapMemoryUsage.used"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me what wrong I am doing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about mappings so I suppose you're using dynamic mapping - you've just indexed documents like these two in your elasticsearch.

Once you visit

> {yourhost}/zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2-2017.10.29/_mapping

you will see that *metric_path* field probably has type **text** which is default for strings. As [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) states:

> A field to index full-text values, such as the body of an email or the description of a product. These fields are analyzed, that is they are passed through an analyzer to convert the string into a list of individual terms before being indexed

So  your field is processed by analyzer and finally you're not executing match against something like this: *zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2.ClientRequest.ReadLatency.Count* but rather against some analyzed form, probably split by periods, and some other special characters.

So if you want to perform filtering like you posted, you should statically define your index before indexing any documents. You don't have to do it for each property, but at least *metric_path* should be defined as **keyword**. So you can start with:

```
PUT {yourhost}/zabbix_test-us-east-2-node2-2017.10.29

 {
    "mappings": {
       "jmx": {
          "properties": {
             "metric_path": {
                "type": "keyword"
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Then you should index your documents. Mapping for other fields will be established by ES dynamically, but both queries attached by you will return exactly one result - just as you expect.